# Writing a "table" from Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How does one write both multiple strings and multiple variable outputs on one line in a file to output?
I know that write() only accepts one argument, though ideally this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
write('Temperature is', X , 'and pressure is', Y)
```

The result would be a table.

Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

```
write('Temperature is {0} and pressure is {1})'.format(X,Y))
```

If you want more control over the output you can do something like this:

```
X = 12.3
Y = 1.23
write('Temperature is {0:.1f} and pressure is {1:.2f})'.format(X,Y))
# writes 'Temperature is 12.3 and pressure is 1.2'
```

Documentation and examples here:  http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/string.html

Answer (score 2):

```
f = open("somefile.txt", "w")
print('Temperature is', X , 'and pressure is', Y, file=f)
```

Comment: He wants to output to a file.